# Lumia 520 outlook saved draft not showing next time

Tags: 8.0, lumia, outlook

I have a Lumia 520. I composed an incomplete email using the Outlook app. Then, after pressing the back button, I was prompted with the following options:

- do you want to save the message in your drafts folder

OR

- do you want to delete message.

I checked the save option, but I don't see the message in the drafts. Where can I find the draft message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phone does not immediately push the draft to the server. You might want to check on the phone.

- Go to the **mail app**
- Tap the menu and select **folders**
- Select the **drafts** folder under the correct email account (you could have more than one)

Comment: Yes that really worked